# cloud front always returns 404 error to browser, how to do I make it return 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Are there settings or configuration options, I can change in cloud front, because it's returning 404 error response, but the code and pages are fine.

Comment: The "code and pages" are not fine.  Your origin server is returning the error, not CloudFront, because CloudFront has no way of generating a 404.  Look at the logs on the server.

Comment: So how do you explain the fact that it returns errors when using the same code base on an ipaddress which doesn't go through cloud front?  Through cloud front the headers return 404, yet the pages still display if a basic static page returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize AWS Cloudfront `Custom Error Response`. You can specify `HTTP Error Code` to be returned by the service when your custom origin is unavailable and returning 4xx, 5xx responses.

You can even set a custom page (page from s3) to be display e.g. 404 html page.

[image]

Comment: Is this case won't it just return error_page.html for all cases where the server returns a 404 error ? which I tried and that's what it does

Answer (score 0):

It will be using the same http status code that the origin responds.

In saying this you can modify it by using a Lambda@Edge function to change the status code.

*Additional Links*

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-custom-error-static-body

Comment: it works find on an ipaddress and doesn't return 404 from the origin

Answer (score 0):

actually found that my nginx.conf was missing something cloud front was looking for

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```